# How to stack or group woocommence product gallery images into the featured product image?

Tags: php, image, templates, woocommerce, gallery

I am trying to group product pictures into a view pictures button that is place inside the feature image on the product page. As shown on the picture below.

How to do something like this in Woocommerce:

[image: how to do this in Woocommerce]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?])(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: This is just a big custom development on product gallery. So you will have to [**override woocommerce templates via your active theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/#section-10) … The templates to be overridden are: [`single-product/product-image.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.4/templates/single-product/product-image.php) and [`single-product/product-thumbnails.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.4/templates/single-product/product-thumbnails.php)